# Git Extensions - Share repositories with users

Tags: git, git-extensions

I am very new to using Git Extensions but need to use it for an upcoming online class. I wanted to know if there is a way to Share a repository/code with people in a different city. A few people are on the same network as myself and others are not. Is this possible to do using ONLY Git Extensions (not GitHub)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Git extensions is a Gui tool that sits on top of the git console tools.  It's not directly a sharing / collaboration tool.  In order to share code, you need a hosted repository like GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, VSTS, or you could host your own.

Sounds like you should just setup a free private repository and invite your students to join it.  Any of the hosters above should have a free service you probably use.